# Principal branch in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the principal branches of $z^{a}, z^{b}, z^{a+b},$ and $z^{ab}$.

Part a) is this true? $$z^{a}z^{b} = z^{a+b}$$
Part b) is this below statement true? $$(z^{a})^{b} = z^{ab}$$

I have no idea what are some approached I need to start to understand the principal branch that does not involve the log and e.

Comment: They are talking about 'principal branch' due to $z^a$ being defined as $e^{a\log(z)}$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod, so principal branch of $z^{a+b}$ is basically $e^{(a+b)log(z)}$?

Comment: ... with the $\log(z)$ being defined as the principal branch of the logarithm, yes.